# How can I copy my TextInput value into a separate variable and then find its length

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native.I am building a react-native app in which i want to copy the content of TextInput component into a separate variable and then to find its length to check if the user has entered some text or not. If user will leave a blank TextInput, an error message will be displayed.

Comment: you can add onChangeText and retrieve the text value on your text input, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onchangetext here is the reference

Comment: can you please show me code how to add onChangeText and retrieve the text value ? It is telling me that a function which Callback that is called when the text input's text changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use onChangeText to get input,

```
export default class UselessTextInput extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { text: '' };
   }

validation = () => {
   this.state.text ? Alert.alert('','Valid') : Alert.alert('','Error');
}

render() {
   return (
     <TextInput
       onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
       value={this.state.text}
     />
     <Button onPress={() => this.validation()}>
       <Text>Validation</Text>
     </Button>
   );
 }
}
```

i hope can help, :)

Comment: you can use this.state.text to get value, if you want apply validation to next inputText, i think you must have to create other validation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind the new value to a separate variable.Simply you can do this.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { text: '' };
}

onChangeText(text) {
   // DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO WITH WHAT USER ENTERED!!!
   if (text) {
      alert('Blank');
   }
   this.setState({ text });
}

render() {
   return (
     <TextInput
       onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
       value={this.state.text}
     />
   );
}
```